# Print an image in Chrome using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

On my website I'd like to create buttons for printing various images. I'm aware that this can be achieved using Javascript. After some research I wrote this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pwin;
function printImg(imgSrc) {
    pwin = window.open(imgSrc, "_blank");
    setTimeout("pwin.print()", 20);
}
</script>
...
<input class="printAndSolve" type="submit" value="Print"
onclick="printImg('original.png')">
```

This opens the image in a new tab but it doesn't show the print dialog.
What have I done wrong?

Further research resulted in a different approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printImg(imgSrc) {
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print
    Window','height=400,width=600');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body ><img src=\'');
    printWindow.document.write(imgSrc);
    printWindow.document.write('\' /></body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.onload = function() { printWindow.print(); };
}
</script>
...
<input class="printAndSolve" type="submit" value="Print"
onclick="printImg('original.png')">
```

This gives me a weird result. When trying to print a small image, the print dialog pops up as it should. But when I try to print a bigger image (covering a whole A4 paper), the dialog does NOT pop up. What on earth is going on?

Bearing in mind what I wish to achieve, what would you guys say is the best approach?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This actually seems to be a browser related problem. The code above works perfectly fine in Firefox and IE. I'm having this issue because I'm developing the website in Chrome. Apparently Chrome doesn't wait for my window content to load before showing the print window. Other browser all seem to first wait for the content to load, then show the print window. 
I have of course tried with the function setTimeout without success.
My question is thus, can anyone show me a workaround for printing images in Chrome?

**SOLVED**

This website proved to be gold: http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.se/2014/01/image-printing-problem-in-google-chrome.html

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the onLoad event to body tag:

```
printWindow.document.write('</head><body onLoad="self.print(); self.close()"><img src=\'');
```